# Running pipelined commands using ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to extract the frequency of the most frequent line in a file using the following command:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c | sort -r | head -1|  xargs
```

I am trying to accomplish from within a Java program, using the ProcessBuilder class. Here is how I am passing to its constructor:

```
ProcessBuilder builder=new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c","sort",fileName,"| uniq -c | sort -r | head -1 | xargs");
```

When I run the program, it just stops executing beyond this line. There are no errors, but the program just halts at this line. What is it that I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including a filename directly into command:

```
ProcessBuilder builder=new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c","sort " + fileName + " | uniq -c | sort -r | head -1 | xargs");
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks @Ivan.